# how to set setCustomValidity() for dynamically added html elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am adding elements dynamically to my view and adding their attributes using jquery attr function as shown below.

```
var input = $("<input type='text' name='"+inputFieldName+"' '>");
input.attr("placeholder", "Required"); 
input.attr("required" , true);      
input.appendTo(container);
```

As I have set `required` to true I am getting default html message. How can I set `setCustomValidity` to some custom message. I have follwoing questions:

1. can I do it using jquery `attr` tag of do I need to call a separate function.
2. If I need to create a seaparate function, how should I go about it

Answer (score 0):

```
var input = $("<input type='text' name='tt'>");
input.attr("placeholder", "Required");
input.attr("required" , true);
input[0].setCustomValidity(); // get native HTML object to set error message 
input.appendTo($('#test'));
```

1. Yes, you can.
2. You need get the native HTML object to set the error message with `setCustomValidity()` method.

Comment: what does `input[0]` refer to?

Comment: I have added `input[0].setCustomValidity("this is custom");` but I am getting the default.